# Downsizing baby formula

Tags: arithmetic, ratio, mixing

I couldn't find a stack exchange for babies, so here goes. We mix ten scoops of formula into 150ml of water to get 200ml of milk. What is the combo I need to make 150ml of milk?

I tried mixing 7.5 scoops with 112.5 ml of water and it still comes out to around 180ml of milk after many tries.

Not sure what laws of mathematics or physics is at work here.

Comment: That's not the sort of formula that we usually see here.

Comment: If 150 ml + 10 scoops = 200 ml, then 1 scoop is equal to 5 ml. So then 7.5 scoops + 112.5 ml should indeed add up to 150 ml. And the ratio of "formula scoop to water" even stays the same in these two. I don't know what's wrong if you cannot get it to be that way.

Comment: ...? SE sites require "on-topic" not "nearest".

Comment: Yes I noticed and fixed it, thank you.

Comment: By the way, do you mean "112.5 ml of water" in the latter part?

Comment: @MattiP. Sorry, it was a typo. I did mean 7.5 scoops and 112.5ml of water as you said. We tried mixing many times using that ratio, but it still comes out to ~180ml. Perhaps the formula powder has some properties that is making the output be more than a simple ratio output.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I thought the question was looking for a mathematical formula to downsize babies.

Comment: Maybe you need to gather more data. Try 2 scoops with 30 ml water, 4 scoops with 60 ml water, 6 scoops with 90 ml water, 8 scoops with 120 ml water. See how much milk you get in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

- Take 112.5 ml of water
- Slowly start adding the formula to the water, and measure the volume after each scoop
- When the volume is the desired amount (150 ml), stop adding

And ta-da, you have 150 ml of milk!

Comment: The problem is that the milk will then be very diluted and may not have the required nutrients.

Comment: @Shahid: Then do it the other way around: take 7.5 scoops of formula and slowly add water until you get 150 ml milk.

Comment: That'd still not work as the objective is to mix the powder and water in the original ratio of 10 scoops to 150ml water as well. I guess we can do trial and error by mixing one scoop for every 15ml water and seeing which comes closest to 150ml.